# ASP binding returning wrong value

Tags: asp.net

I have a hyperlink with the querystring binded to a autonumber field in an access database but it is returning negative versions of the number instead of positive, for example -1 for 1, -2 for 2, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not the data itself? Try to subscribe to the `DataBound` event on the binding control and analyze the `DataItem` using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour occurs while using ADO.NET autonumber's in DataSet.

While the DataSet isn't actually update the data on the server, it inserts its own unique IDs: -1, -2, -3, etc.

After updating, these IDs is replaced by DB IDs.

However, it is normal :)